# Android: Problema CoordinatorLayout con GridView

Tags: android, android-layout

Dentro de un CoordinatorLayout tengo un GridView, el problema que tengo es que solo se ven las dos primeras imagenes del GridView y las restantes ya no, espero y me puedan ayudar.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/background_light"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true" >

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/main.appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true" >

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/main.collapsing"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
        app:title="Bienvenido">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="30dp"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="8dp"
            android:id="@+id/data_checkin" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/main.toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeScot"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />
    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">

        <GridView
            android:id="@+id/grid_view"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:columnWidth="300dp"
            android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:numColumns="2"
            android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
            android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:clickable="true" />

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab_picture"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:src="@drawable/picture"
    android:tint="#FFF"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/main.appbar"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab_home"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:src="@drawable/home"
    android:tint="#FFF"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/main.appbar"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|fill_horizontal|end" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

De esta manera setteo las imagenes al GridView

```
if (checkIn.getImages().size() > 0){//valido de que existan imagenes
        gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this, checkIn.getImages()));//seteo las imagenes al gridView
    }//./if
```

Comment: ¿A que te refieres con que sólo se ven las dos primeras imágenes? No sé si te referirás a esto pero tienes que el `GridView` tenga solamente dos columnas con esta propiedad `android:numColumns="2"`

Comment: Si tengo solo dos columnas y solo en esas dos columnas se van a colocar todas las imagenes intento mostrar diez imagenes pero solo se muestran dos, una en una columna y la otra en la restante

Comment: ¿Puedes mostrar también el código en el que añades esas diez imágenes?

Comment: Intenta añadiendo android:fillViewport="true" a tu NestedScrollView

Comment: Es decir quieres mostrar la totalidad de las imágenes, es decir que el control se expande para que quepan todas, perdiendo su scroll propio y usar el de NestedScrollView, te he dejado una respuesta

Comment: Muchas gracias, deja lo checo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Intenta agregar android:fillViewport="true" a tu NestedScrollView
Ejemplo:

```
 <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" >
```

**Editado**

Agrega el siguiente código en el método donde declares a tu Gridview, ejemplo:

```
ViewCompat.setNestedScrollingEnabled(gridView, true);
```

Comment: Si ya muestra mas imagenes pero ahora lo que pasa es que el gridview no hace scroll para que muestre todas, osea solo se ven hasta donde la resolucion de la pantalla le permite pero no el total de imagenes

Comment: @Javierfr actualice mi repuesta, pruebalo

Comment: Gracias Keops ya quedo, agradesco tu ayuda :3

Comment: @Javierfr me da gusto, por favor, da clic sobre la palomita que te aparece  para dar como buena  o acertada la respuesta.

Comment: LIsto y muchas gracias Keops

Comment: @Javierfr Eliminaste la publicación y ya no alcance a leer todo lo que pusiste, pero que bueno que se soluciono, saludos

Comment: Publique lo anterior porque no me quedaba la solucion de mostrar todas las imagenes, entonces estaba buscando otras maneras de mostrar ese GridView junto con el TextView, pero vi que comentaste entonces rapido fui a checar y que si me quedo :3. Muchas gracias Keops

Answer (score 1):

Si solo quieres mostrar un listado de imágenes, lo mejor seria cambiar el `NestedScrollView` por un `RecyclerView` que puede mostrarse como un `GridView` o `ListView`, más eficiente en listar imágenes o datos pesados.

Los elementos `ListView` y `GridView` cuando están dentro de un `NestedScrollView` su `height` es a la porpoción de lo que ocupa un elemento en su representación.
Para poder hacer que el `GridView` se expande a todos sus elementos debes crear un componente propio y modificar su tamaño.

```
public class ExpandableHeightGridView extends GridView {

    boolean expanded = false;

    public ExpandableHeightGridView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public ExpandableHeightGridView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public ExpandableHeightGridView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,
            int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public boolean isExpanded() {
        return expanded;
    }

    @Override
    public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        // HACK! TAKE THAT ANDROID!
        if (isExpanded()) {
            // Calculate entire height by providing a very large height hint.
            // View.MEASURED_SIZE_MASK represents the largest height possible.
            int expandSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(MEASURED_SIZE_MASK,
                    MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
            super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, expandSpec);

            ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = getLayoutParams();
            params.height = getMeasuredHeight();
        } else {
            super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        }
    }

    public void setExpanded(boolean expanded) {
        this.expanded = expanded;
    }
}
```

Para definirlo dentro de tu layout debes cambiar la ruta `com.example` con tu `propia ruta de paquete`

```
<com.example.ExpandableHeightGridView
    android:id="@+id/my_grid"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:horizontalSpacing="2dp"
    android:isScrollContainer="false"
    android:numColumns="4"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:verticalSpacing="20dp" />
```

Por código si quieres hacer que se expande a su totalidad

```
mGrid = (ExpandableHeightGridView) findViewById(R.id.my_grid);
mGrid.setExpanded(true);
```

Extraído de [esa respuesta de SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8483078/3464919)

**Extra**

Lo mismo pero con un `ListView`

```
public class ExpandableListView extends ListView {

    boolean expanded = false;

    public ExpandableListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defaultStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defaultStyle);
    }

    public boolean isExpanded() {
        return expanded;
    }

    public void setExpanded(boolean expanded) {
        this.expanded = expanded;
    }

    @Override
    public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        // HACK!  TAKE THAT ANDROID!
        if (isExpanded()) {         
            // Calculate entire height by providing a very large height hint.
            // View.MEASURED_SIZE_MASK represents the largest height possible.
            int expandSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(MEASURED_SIZE_MASK,
                        MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
            super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, expandSpec);

            LayoutParams params = getLayoutParams();
            params.height = getMeasuredHeight();
        } else {
            super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        }
    }
}
```

Extraído de [esa respuesta SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4536955/3464919)